# WPF XML DataBinding not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have below xml file. I have copied it into my project debug/bin folder & have also attached to my project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?> 
- <NorthwindDataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/NorthwindDataSet.xsd">
- <Customers>
  <CustomerID>ALFKI</CustomerID> 
  <CompanyName>Alfreds Futterkiste</CompanyName> 
  <ContactName>Maria Anders</ContactName> 
  <ContactTitle>Sales Representative</ContactTitle> 
  <Address>Obere Str. 57</Address> 
  <City>Berlin</City> 
  <PostalCode>12209</PostalCode> 
  <Country>Germany</Country> 
  <Phone>030-0074321</Phone> 
  <Fax>030-0076545</Fax> 
  </Customers>
- <Customers>
  <CustomerID>ANATR</CustomerID> 
  <CompanyName>Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados</CompanyName> 
  <ContactName>Ana Trujillo</ContactName> 
  <ContactTitle>Owner</ContactTitle> 
  <Address>Avda. de la Constitución 2222</Address> 
  <City>México D.F.</City> 
  <PostalCode>05021</PostalCode> 
  <Country>Mexico</Country> 
  <Phone>(5) 555-4729</Phone> 
  <Fax>(5) 555-3745</Fax> 
  </Customers>
</NorthwindDataSet>
```

I want to bind properties like CustomerName, City in my WPF application. I tried to bind it in XAML as below, but not getting success. Need suggetsion, what I am doing wrong.

```
<Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="NorthData" Source="Northwind.xml" XPath="/Customers"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="{Binding XPath=Address,FallbackValue=BindingFailed,Source={StaticResource NorthData}}" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="118,94,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127" />
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource NorthData},XPath=City,FallbackValue=BindingFailed}" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="128,144,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Did you look at the OUTPUT window after you run the application? Usually it shows binding errors there. Also is the XML file an embedded resource?

Comment: I got it to work if I prefix "NorthwindDataSet/" to the xpath at the top. So the XPath was "/Customers", but I changed it to "NorthwindDataSet/Customers" and that worked.

Comment: @Martin - Thanks for the suggestion. Setting XPath = NorthwindDataSet/Customers worked for me. But I find that ListBox contains only one city = "Berlin", I am expecting city - "México D.F." as well in the list. Can you please suggest me how to achieve it? I tried setting DisplayMemberPath property along with XPath in ListBox but it didn't work. I have another question, if I set xmlns="NorthwindDatSet.xsd" attribute in .xml file & copy .xsd file in debug/bin folder of project then Binding gets failed. I also attached both updated .xml & .xsd files to my project. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Using your code I modified the XPath a little bit, and removed the reference to the XSD which you didn't provide, and it worked:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="NorthData" XPath="NorthwindDataSet/Customers">
            <x:XData>
                <NorthwindDataSet xmlns="">
                    <Customers>
                        <CustomerID>ALFKI</CustomerID>
                        <CompanyName>Alfreds Futterkiste</CompanyName>
                        <ContactName>Maria Anders</ContactName>
                        <ContactTitle>Sales Representative</ContactTitle>
                        <Address>Obere Str. 57</Address>
                        <City>Berlin</City>
                        <PostalCode>12209</PostalCode>
                        <Country>Germany</Country>
                        <Phone>030-0074321</Phone>
                        <Fax>030-0076545</Fax>
                    </Customers>
                    <Customers>
                        <CustomerID>ANATR</CustomerID>
                        <CompanyName>Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados</CompanyName>
                        <ContactName>Ana Trujillo</ContactName>
                        <ContactTitle>Owner</ContactTitle>
                        <Address>Avda. de la Constitucion 2222</Address>
                        <City>Mexico D.F.</City>
                        <PostalCode>05021</PostalCode>
                        <Country>Mexico</Country>
                        <Phone>(5) 555-4729</Phone>
                        <Fax>(5) 555-3745</Fax>
                    </Customers>
                </NorthwindDataSet>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="{Binding XPath=Address
            , FallbackValue=BindingFailed
            , Source={StaticResource NorthData}}" 
               Height="28"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
               Margin="118,94,0,0" Name="label1" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127" />
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource NorthData}
            , XPath=City
            , FallbackValue=BindingFailed}" 
                 Height="100" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                 Margin="128,144,0,0" 
                 Name="listBox1" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                 Width="120" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the DataContext to your XML

```
<Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="NorthData" Source="Northwind.xml" XPath="/Customers"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource NorthData}">
        <Label Content="{Binding XPath=Address,FallbackValue=BindingFailed,Source={StaticResource NorthData}}" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="118,94,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127" />
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource NorthData},XPath=City,FallbackValue=BindingFailed}" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="128,144,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: He is setting the SOURCE in the binding. So even if he sets the DataContext, it will not use the DataContext, but try to use the Source instead.